# sql not returning rows containing null values

Tags: php, sql, null

I am getting row when searched and matched pir_no having other fields with No Null values.
But file_no field may have NULL so records having pir_no NULL not showing on webpage but query getting result I think because I M USING GET TO CATCH header and values and values are showing in url box/address bar.

Help.How can i show full records even if some columns have NULL.

my table fields are as...
pir_sr  pir_no  pir_type    pir_dor pir_fin_year    pir_related file_status file_no  pir_status pir_progress    online_status   pir_remark
field file_no may containg NULL VALUES

mysql query is

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from pir_detail WHERE pir_no = $query_pir";
```

result assignment and checking rows ----

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        $row_num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

if containing rows then action -

```
if($row_num>0)
        {
            //while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                header('Location: add_case_detail_form.php?pir_no='.$row['pir_no'].'&type='.$row['pir_type'] .
                '&dor='.$row['pir_dor'].'&related='.$row['pir_related'].'&fileno='.$row['file_no'].
                '&pirstatus='.$row['pir_status'].'&pirprogress='.$row['pir_progress']);
            }
        }else
            {

             header('Location:add_case_detail_form.php?result=""');
            }
```

at search page - getting result from header and printing them as --

```
f(isset($_GET['pir_no']) && !empty($_GET['pir_no']) AND 
                            isset($_GET['type']) && !empty($_GET['type']) AND
                            isset($_GET['dor']) && !empty($_GET['dor']) AND
                            isset($_GET['related']) && !empty($_GET['related']) AND
                            isset($_GET['fileno']) && !empty($_GET['fileno'])AND
                            isset($_GET['pirstatus']) && !empty($_GET['pirstatus'])AND
                            isset($_GET['pirprogress']) && !empty($_GET['pirprogress'])
                            ){

                        echo("PIR No: "."<a href='#addcase' class='a'>".$_GET['pir_no']."</a>".
                                ","." TYPE: ".$_GET['type'] .
                                ","." Received Date: ".$_GET['dor'].
                                ","." Related/DIG: ".$_GET['related'].
                                ","." File No: ".$_GET['fileno'].
                                ","." PIR Status: ".$_GET['pirstatus'].
                                ","." PIR Progress: ".$_GET['pirprogress']

                                );}
```

Comment: Having issues following completely, but if pir_no is NULL in the database, and $query_pir is something other than NULL, its never going to match. You can of course, check for IS NULL against pir_no. Or you can OR it like: WHERE (pir_no = $query_pir OR pir_no IS NULL)

Answer (score 0):

If `pir_no` can contain `NULL` values and you want to search on that, you have to use

```
WHERE pir_no IS NULL
```

Note that a `NULL` value is something different from an empty value.

Comment: pir_no is primary key CAN NOT contain NULL. file_no is CONTAINING NULL VALUES i want to get full row matching pir_no. If tried to use IFNULL(pir_no, 0) in sql but with this whole query not working i dont know why.

Comment: But you said: "so records having pir_no NULL not showing on webpage". Please post your table schema, what you do, what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: Sorry to hijack, @BartFriederichs - But if as you've said in the same comment, pir_no is pkey, and yet you're still checking IFNULL on pir_no. I'm mighty confused now. Please post your schema so we can see :)

Comment: i am checking IFNULL ON file_no not pir_no

Comment: pir_sr int(20) NO PRI NULL auto_increment
pir_no bigint(25) NO UNI NULL 
pir_type text NO  NULL 
pir_dor date NO  NULL 
pir_fin_year varchar(20) NO  NULL 
pir_related text NO  NULL 
file_status text NO  NULL 
file_no int(10) YES  NULL 
pir_status text NO  NULL 
pir_progress text NO  NULL 
online_status text NO  NULL 
pir_remark text NO  NULL

Comment: file_no can be null.

Comment: sorry@BartFriederichs I wrote pir_no instead of file_no.